# codeigniter pagination-result not display at the next page

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I have implemented the CI Pagination into the system correctly. i have set limit 25 result per page. but i like to let user to change the limit such as 50,75,100 if they wish. The system work perfectly in first page if the user choose to view 50 result, but when the user click on the next page link or do sort table column, it return to limit 25.

here is my code.

view:

```
 <?php

    if(isset($_POST['num']))
    {
        $selected_option = $_POST['num'] ;
    }else{
        $selected_option ='';
    }

    $options = array(25,50,75,100);
    ?>
    <form id="myForm" method="post" action = "">
    Show <select name="num" onchange="document.getElementById('myForm').submit()">
    <?php
    $selected_option = $_POST['num'];
    foreach($options as $v){
        if($v == $selected_option){
            $selected = 'selected = "selected"';
        }else{
            $selected = '';
        }
        echo "<option value='$v' $selected>$v</option>";
    }
    ?>    
    </select> entries
    </form>


<table style="width:100%">
    <thread>
        <?php foreach ($fields as $field_name => $field_display): ?>
        <th <?php if($sort_by == $field_name) echo "class=\"sort_$sort_order\"" ?>>
            <?php echo anchor("rps/index/$field_name/".
            (($sort_order == 'asc' && $sort_by == $field_name) ? 'desc' : 'asc'), $field_display); ?>
        </th>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </thread>

    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($record as $key): ?>
        <tr>
            <?php foreach ($fields as $field_name => $field_display): ?>
            <td><?php echo $key->$field_name; ?></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    </tbody>
</table>

<?php if (strlen($pagination)): ?>

    Pages: <?php echo $pagination; ?>


<?php endif; ?>
```

controller:

```
    public function index($sort_by='player_item', $sort_order='asc',$offset=0)
    {

      if (isset($_POST['num']) && !empty($_POST['num']))
            $limit = $this->input->post('num');

            else
            $limit= 25;



            $data7['fields'] = array(
                    'id' => 'ID',
                    'time' => 'Time',
                    'player_item' => 'Player Choose',
                    'comp_item'=> 'Computer Choose',
                    'result'=> 'Result'
                    );


            $this->load->model('rps_result');
            $result = $this->rps_result->history($limit,$offset,$sort_by,$sort_order);

            $data7['record'] = $result['rows'];
            $data7['num_record'] = $result['number_rows'];

            //pagination
            $this->load->library('pagination');
            $this->load->helper('url'); 
            $config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/xampp/CodeIgniter/index.php/rps/index/$sort_by/$sort_order";
            $config['total_rows'] = $data7['num_record'];
            $config['per_page'] = $limit;
            $config['uri_segment'] = 5;
            $this->pagination->initialize($config);
            $data7['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
            $data7['sort_by'] = $sort_by;
            $data7['sort_order'] = $sort_order;

            $this->load->view('rps_result', $data7);
}
```

model:

```
 function history($limit,$offset,$sort_by,$sort_order)
  {
        $sort_order = ($sort_order == 'desc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';
        $sort_columns = array('id','player_item','comp_item','result','time');
        $sort_by = (in_array($sort_by, $sort_columns)) ? $sort_by : 'time';
        //result query

        $query = $this->db->select('id,player_item,comp_item,result,time')
               ->from('rps')
               ->limit($limit,$offset)
               ->order_by($sort_by,$sort_order);

        $ret['rows'] = $query->get()->result();



        //count query
        $query1 = $this->db->select('count(*) as count', FALSE)
                ->from('rps');

        $tmp = $query1->get()->result();
        $ret['number_rows'] = $tmp[0]->count;

        return $ret;

  }
```

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass 'num' from page to page. When you select the value, it gets the form submitted and the page is reloaded. But it doesn't use $_POST['num'] on the next pages, the value doesn't pass trough. The easyest way to fix this, would be to store the value in a cookie. In your controller instead of `$limit = $this->input->post('num');` do

```
if($this->input->post('num')){      
  setcookie('pagination_limit',$this->input->post('num')); 
  $limit = $this->input->post('num');
}elseif($this->input->cookie('pagination_limit')){
  $limit = $this->input->cookie('pagination_limit', true);
}else{$limit = 25;}
```

In your view, you should also repalace `$_POST['num']` with `$this->input->cookie('pagination_limit', true);`

Comment: is it replaced all $_POST['num'] with $this->input->cookie('pagination_limit', true) in view?

Comment: yup, that too. I made new correction. Sorry I don't test this code, so I don't always get it right first time

Comment: it work on pagination..but when i do the table column sorting, it also change the limit...

Comment: Yes, the cookie is set for the exact uri. Must use `setcookie('pagination_limit',$this->input->post('num'), '0', '/');`. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Comment: now the problem is when reload the page, it initialize limit to 25. but when i  click on next page, it goes back to the value that store at cookies .i try to delete cookies but not working.

Comment: The value would be set via the selected value in the form. What does your form show when you reload? It should correspond to cookie value.

Comment: is it possible to delete the cookies or initialize the value to 25 when first time access or after reload the page...i try use delete_cookie('pagination_limit');  but not work..

Comment: If 3rd parameter is set to 0, or omitted, the cookie will expire at the end of the session (when the browser closes). What you have, is more then one cookie set in your browser messing up your thing. Delete all your domain cookies and start over, or open another browser. There are browsers, like Chrome that accept Add-on apps, that help you manage cookies.